# Simple Counter Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Today I'm working on making a simple counter with HTML / CSS and JS.

My javascript isn't working and I don't know why.. I read a lot on the internet and tried to add "async" but it seems that my code needs a review

```js
let counter = document.getElementById('counter');
let increaseButton = document.getElementById('increase');
let decreaseButton = document.getElementById("decrease");
let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
let count = 0;

function functionIncrease() {
    count ++;
    counter.innerHTML(count);
    color();
}
function functionDecrease() {
    count--;
    counter.innerHTML(count);
    color();
}
function functionReset() {
    count = 0;
    counter.innerHTML(count);
    color();
}
function color() {
    if (count > 0) {
        counter.style.color = "green";
    } else if (count > 0) {
        counter.style.color = "red";
    }
}

increaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionIncrease());
decreaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionDecrease());
resetButton.addEventListener("click", functionReset())
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>My Simple Counter</h1>
    <p id="counter">0</p>
    <div class="button">
        <button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        <button id="increase">Increase</button>
    </div>
</main>
```

I think it's just a stupid error, but I really need your help !

Thank you!

Comment: `counter.innerHTML is not a function`, but a scalar property: `counter.innerHTML = count`. Though since `count` is not HTML, `textContent` would be better: `counter.textContent = count`. EDIT: Also what Luis said.

Comment: As the error says;`innerHTML` is not a function- its a property....so `counter.innerHTML = "Foo";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error says `innerHTML` is not a function, it's a variable.
change it to `=`

And remove the brackets of the listeners, you should **pass the function reference** not call it.

```js
let counter = document.getElementById('counter');
let increaseButton = document.getElementById('increase');
let decreaseButton = document.getElementById("decrease");
let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
let count = 0;

function functionIncrease() {
    count ++;
    counter.innerHTML = count+"";
    color();
}
function functionDecrease() {
    count--;
    counter.innerHTML = count+"";
    color();
}
function functionReset() {
    count = 0;
    counter.innerHTML = count+"";
    color();
}
function color() {
    if (count > 0) {
        counter.style.color = "green";
    } else if (count > 0) {
        counter.style.color = "red";
    }
}

increaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionIncrease);
decreaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionDecrease);
resetButton.addEventListener("click", functionReset)
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>My Simple Counter</h1>
    <p id="counter">0</p>
    <div class="button">
        <button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        <button id="increase">Increase</button>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many improvements to make. Clean and efficient coding will also resolve the issue at hand by itself.

1. Don't add a single eventListener to every button itself that will call an independent function. Use `querySelectorAll` to address all buttons in one call. You get a Node-List which you can use the `forEach` iteration on.
2. Use an event delegation to check what element has been clicked. Then you can return the id of the clicked button with `event.target.id`.
3. Use a switch statement to either decrease, increase, or reset the counter instead of using independent functions with literally 2/3 of the same content.
4. Use `textContent` which is faster then `innerHTML`as the DOm doesn't need to be re-parsed. Also, it poses no security issue of a potential XSS Injection.
5. Instead of calling a new function to color the counter, simply use a `ternary conditional operator`.

```js
let counter = document.querySelector('#counter'),
    button = document.querySelectorAll('.button button'),
    count = 0;

button.forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case 'decrease':
        count--;
        break;
      case 'reset':
        count = 0;
        break;
      case 'increase':
        count++;
        break;
    }
    counter.textContent = count;
    counter.style.color = (count > 0) ? 'green' : 'red';
  })
)
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>My Simple Counter</h1>
  <p id="counter">0</p>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <button id="increase">Increase</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Issues Found**

- Dont call the listener function while registering the event listner. Just mention the function reference. Just like `increaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionIncrease);`
- Also the innerHTML should be set with `counter.innerHTML = count`

**Fixed Code**

```js
let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let increaseButton = document.getElementById("increase");
let decreaseButton = document.getElementById("decrease");
let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
let count = 0;

function functionIncrease() {
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  color();
}
function functionDecrease() {
  count--;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  color();
}
function functionReset() {
  count = 0;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  color();
}
function color() {
  if (count > 0) {
    counter.style.color = "green";
  } else if (count > 0) {
    counter.style.color = "red";
  }
}

increaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionIncrease);
decreaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionDecrease);
resetButton.addEventListener("click", functionReset);
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>My Simple Counter</h1>
  <p id="counter">0</p>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <button id="increase">Increase</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your addEventListener, you have to change with functions names.

Also the .innerHTML was wrong : `counter.innerHTML(count);` to `counter.innerHTML = count;`

```js
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
var increaseButton = document.getElementById('increase');
var decreaseButton = document.getElementById("decrease");
var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
var count = 0;

function functionIncrease() {
    count ++;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
    color();
}
function functionDecrease() {
    count--;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
    color();
}
function functionReset() {
    count = 0;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
    color();
}
function color() {
    if (count > 0) {
        counter.style.color = "green";
    } else if (count > 0) {
        counter.style.color = "red";
    }
}

increaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionIncrease);
decreaseButton.addEventListener("click", functionDecrease);
resetButton.addEventListener("click", functionReset)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Counter</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
    <body>

        <main>
            <h1>My Simple Counter</h1>
            <p id="counter">0</p>
            <div class="button">
                <button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
                <button id="reset">Reset</button>
                <button id="increase">Increase</button>
            </div>
        </main>
        
        <script src="./script.js" async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let counterDisplayElem = document.querySelector('.counter-display');
let counterMinusElem = document.querySelector('.counter-minus');
let counterPlusElem = document.querySelector('.counter-plus');
let reset=document.querySelector('.reset');
let count = 0;

updateDisplay();

counterPlusElem.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    count++;
    updateDisplay();
    color();
}) ;

counterMinusElem.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    count--;
    updateDisplay();
    color();
});

reset.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    count=0;
    updateDisplay();
});

function updateDisplay(){
    counterDisplayElem.innerHTML = count;
};

function color() {
    if (count > 0) {
        counterDisplayElem.style.color = "green";
    } else if (count < 0) {
        counterDisplayElem.style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="counter-display">(..)</h1>
<button class="counter-minus">-</button>
<button class="counter-plus">+</button>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).